# Xamarin Forms Prism Activity Indicator overlay when clicking custom synbutton on Toolbar

Tags: xamarin.forms, overlay, prism, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

Im trying to show an Overlay with an activityIndicator by clicking an custom sync button in the toolbar. The Button makes an API call to get datas from my backend.

Im using Xamarin forms with the Prism Plugin

This is my MasterDetailPage Xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems >
    <ToolbarItem Command="{Binding SyncCommand}" Icon="sync32.png">
    </ToolbarItem>
</MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
<MasterDetailPage.Master  >


    <ContentPage Title="Default" 
                 BackgroundColor="Gray">   
        <StackLayout Padding="0,60,0,0">
            <ListView x:Name="Menu" 
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                      HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                     SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout MinimumHeightRequest="48"
                                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                         Spacing="40">
                                <Label Text="{Binding TitleKey}" 
                                       TextColor="White" 
                                       FontSize="20" 
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:ListViewItemSelectedBehavior Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand }"/>
                </ListView.Behaviors>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage>
        <AbsoluteLayout
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ActivityIndicator  
            Color="#69d2e7"  
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,
                                    Factor=0.33}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Height,
                                    Factor=0.33}"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
            IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
            />


        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

This is my MasterDetail xaml cs

```
  public SMasterDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Menu.ItemSelected += async (s, e) =>
        {
            Menu.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
            await Task.Delay(200);
        };
    }
```

When im clicking on The Sync button in the toolbar the ViewModel gets the datas from the backend and populate an ObservableCollection. Im setting IsBusy to true and after that to false.

But I cant see the overlay. Is their any solution how to show the activityIndicator overlay on each page by clicking the sync button?

Comment: In the XAML for your `ActivityIndicator`, perhaps you should change the `XConstraint`'s `Property` to `Width` instead of `Height`? Also you might try adding `await Task.Delay(1000);` into your sync method just so you can be sure that the command will run long enough for you to see anything happen.

Comment: Ive tried it with setting it to the center and with just never setting IsBusy back to false so that i will see it but nothing changed

Comment: What if you just put `true` for `IsVisible`, `IsRunning`, and `IsEnabled` to rule out binding issues? Then if that still does not work it must be a UI issue so you could try to comment out your `AbsoluteLayout` XAML code so all you have is the `ActivityIndicator` showing on the `MasterDetailPage.Detail` which would help to rule out placement issues.